# Select from two tables at the same time?

Tags: mysql

I need to merge to tables in my query, so I can select as if it were one.

Table A:

```
Objeto | Atributo
1           a
```

Table B:

```
Palabra | Atributo
2           b
3           b
```

In my query I want to select from both so I need to somehow accommodate all rows in one table, in this example that should be:

```
Objeto | Atributo
1           a
2           b
3           b
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select Objecto, Atributo
from table A
UNION ALL
select Palabra, Atributo
from table B
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for something called ***[UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html)***

Answer (score 1):

It's not a join (set multiplication), it's a union (set addition):

```
SELECT  objecto, atributo
FROM    a
UNION ALL
SELECT  palabra, atributo
FROM    b
```

Answer (score 1):

You need something like:

```
select objeto, atributo from tableA
union all
select palabra as objeto, atributo from tableB
order by 1 asc
```

The union will ensure all rows are included from both tables<sup>(a)</sup> and the `order by` clause will sort them correctly, on the off-chance you have disparate or identical `objeto/palabra` columns.

You may also want to consider making this a view of some sort if it's likely to be useful in many places - that will greatly simplify your client code.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> This is one of the options. The other is to just use `union` on its own but this will remove duplicate rows, which may not be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a UNION statement

```
select * from table_a
UNION
select Palabra as Objecto, atributo from table_b
```

Comment: thanks just one question, where do I add the where clause so it selects from both? I tried putting it on the end and I didn't get correct results

Comment: @Liso22 where clause will come after from clause. that is you will ahve to add two where clauses to filter the result.